# Trigger isTest coverage stuck on 61%

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, failing-tests

I have already spent few hours trying to figure out why I'm stuck on 61% and try to add or remove the test methods but no avail.

I have the following test class that is only getting 61% coverage on my trigger.

Any suggestions on improving my test coverage?

//my trigger

```
trigger WorkCompletedTrigger on Work_Order__c (after update) 
{
    List<Id> WOIdList = new List<Id>();
    public Date CompletionDate {get; set;}
    public Decimal VINValue {get; set;}

    for(Work_Order__c wo : trigger.New)
    {
        if(wo.Status__c == 'Completed')
        {
           WOIdList.add(wo.Id); 
           CompletionDate = wo.Comp_Date__c;
           VINValue = wo.VINValue__c;
        }
    } 

    List<Maintain__c> maintList = [SELECT Id, Name, Mtr_ID__c, Current_Completed__c, Last_Completed__c FROM Maintain__c WHERE Current_Completed__c =: WOIdList LIMIT 1 ];

    if(maintList.size() > 0)
    {
        for(Maintain__c m: maintList)
        {
            m.Last_Completed__c = m.Current_Completed__c;
            update m; 

            if(String.isNotBlank(m.Mtr_ID__c))
            {
                Reading__c mr = new Reading__c();
                mr = ReadingClass.createEntry(m.Mtr_ID__c, CompletionDate, VINValue);
            }
            else
            {
                system.debug('blank');
            }                        
        }        
    }
}
```

//My Test

```
static testMethod void run_Work_Order_Insert_Test() 
{ 
    Work_Order__c testWorkOrder = TestFactory.buildTestWorkOrder('description', 'instructions', 'preserve' );
    insert testWorkOrder;  
    System.assertEquals(testWorkOrder.Description__c, 'description');  
}

static testMethod void run_Work_Order_After_Status_Change_Update_Test() 
{ 
    Work_Order__c testWorkOrder = TestFactory.buildTestWorkOrder('description', 'instructions', 'preserve');
    insert testWorkOrder;

    testWorkOrder.Status__c = 'Completed';

    if(testWorkOrder.Status__c == 'Completed')
    {
      testWorkOrder.Current_Completed__c = System.Today();           
      testWorkOrder.VINValue = 123.00;
      update testWorkOrder; 
    } 
    System.assertEquals(testWorkOrder.VINValue__c, 123.00);  
}
```

I have tried to add other test methods but none increase my code coverage %

Comment: Exactly which sections of code are covered and which ones are not?

Comment: How do you check that, I'm new to SF

Comment: Does your TestFactory.buildTestWorkOrder method also create a Maintain__c object?  I don't see you creating one in your code.  If the factory doesn't create one then the trigger will never return anything and won't get past the <code>if(maintList.size() > 0)</code> condition

Comment: its not creating under the `TestFactory.buildTestWorkOrder` but i tried with separate method that creates Maintain__c object but still getting the same percent

Comment: Remember it's not enough just to create the Maintain__c object, it also must have the Id of the Work_Order__c in it's "Current_Completed__c" field so that the query will return the record properly.  It would be good to show the code that creates that object also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check your code coverage first to to Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution and click on the "Options" button.  Ensure that the "Store Only Aggregate Code Coverage" checkbox is NOT CHECKED

[image]

Then run your test class to ensure it captures the coverage correctly.  Once you've done that open the Developer Console Setup > Developer Console

[image]

In the lower left area of the Developer Console locate the "Test" tab click on it, and find the class or trigger that you want to check coverage for.  Double click the trigger to bring it up in the console view.

[image]

Now in the top left you should see a drop down like button that says "Code Coverage: All Tests xx%" where xx is the total coverage.

[image]

You can use the total coverage to see where you are lacking (Red Highlighting), you can also check that drop down button for specific test methods.

This will let you know what methods cover what code, and give you total coverage.

Here is some official [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&language=en_US)

Once you've checked what's not covered you'll have a better idea of what you need to do.

**Update**

> okay I able to find out how to check which code is covered and which one is not the NOT COVERED part is for loop

This means that the query

```
List<Maintain__c> maintList = [SELECT Id, Name, Mtr_ID__c, Current_Completed__c, Last_Completed__c FROM Maintain__c WHERE Current_Completed__c =: WOIdList LIMIT 1 ];
```

is not returning any results.  You need to add it in your test methods like below.

```
static testMethod void run_Work_Order_Insert_Test() 
{ 
    Work_Order__c testWorkOrder = TestFactory.buildTestWorkOrder('description', 'instructions', 'preserve' );
    insert testWorkOrder;  

    Maintain__c main = new Maintain__c();
    main.Current_Completed__c = testWorkOrder.Id;
    insert main;

    System.assertEquals(testWorkOrder.Description__c, 'description');  
}
```

Add any other fields necessary for the creation of the Maintain__c object.  You'll need to do this in both of your test methods.

Comment: 1+ I have already had `Disable Parallel Apex Testing` checked and when I go to developer console and I see the `Code Coverage: None`

Comment: @AbuHamzah You also want to disable "Store Only Aggregate Code Coverage" and rerun your test before checking.  Also click the button anyway, sometimes it'll say Code Coverage: None when you first open the class, but the dropdown will show All Tests

Comment: okay I able to find out how to check which code is covered and which one is not the NOT COVERED part is `for loop`

Comment: @AbuHamzah I've updated my answer with how to create the Maintain__c object in your test, so that it will be queried in your trigger.